# Defining a generic real function in Isabelle 2015

Tags: isabelle

In Isabelle2014 I was able to define a generic function which takes a natural number and a real number and outputs a real number in the following way:

```
definition example :: "nat ⇒ real ⇒ real"
where "example i = real"
```

However, I am unable to this in Isabelle2015. I get the following error:

*Bad head of lhs: "λx. example i (real x)"

The error(s) above occurred in definition:

"λx. example i (real x) ≡ real"*

Has the method of defining a generic real function changed in the newer version of Isabelle? How can I define a generic function as I used to?

I've looked through the newer Isabelle documentation however I have been unable to find anything which relates to the following case.

Comment: What precisely do you mean by “generic”?

Comment: Do you want to define a function ignoring its first argument, or a function converting the first argument from nat to real, ignoring the second argument? In both cases, the example you will not do what you want, neither in 2014 or 2015.

Comment: @LarsNoschinski I want to define a function which ignores the first argument and outputs a real number using the second argument. The output will be of type real, however I want to avoid using a specific functional form. How would I be able to achieve this?

Comment: @JoachimBreitner Apologies for the confusion; by generic I mean I want to avoid explicitly defining a function and instead just work with a real output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Myself, I always have on `declare[[show_sorts=true]]` and `declare[[show_consts=true]]`, so I see things about type classes and types that I otherwise wouldn't see and think about.

In Isabelle2015, you have

```
term "real :: 'a∷real_of => real".
```

But in Isabelle2014, it's

```
term "real :: 'a::type => real".
```

Apparently, the type class `real_of` is new in Isabelle2015.

I use the command `print_classes` in both Isabelle2015 and Isabelle2014, and search on the results in the output panel.

Nothing shows up for `real_of` in Isabelle2014, but in Isabelle2015 I get

```
class real_of:
  supersort: type
  parameters:
    real :: 'a => real
  instances:
    int :: real_of
    nat :: real_of
```

This shows that only `int` and `nat` have been instantiated for `real_of`. You can change your `example` to this:

```
definition example :: "nat => 'a::real_of => real" where 
  "example i = real"
```

Comment: Your fix is most probably not what the OP wants, although it points to the source of the problem: In 2014, real could be applied to convert any term to a real -- although definitions only existed for int and nat, so you couldn't prove anything interesting for other types. Not even `real (x :: real) = x`. In 2015, the type has been restricted to reduce confusion by essentially meaningless terms.

Comment: @Lars, I guess the OP could instantiate `real` as `real_of`. I've gotten lots of mileage out of a previous answer you gave involving `Resources.master_directory (Toplevel.theory_of state)`.

Comment: The simpler (and probably more sensible) solution would be to use `id` instead of `real` (why convert something which does not need to be converted?)

Answer (score 0):

When the argument is already of type real, then you do not need any conversion function, and the function you want is just:

```
definition example :: "nat ⇒ real ⇒ real" where
  "example i x = x"
```

Alternatively, if you want to omit the second argument, use `example i = id` instead.